# How do we prove that $[n+1/2]+[n+2/4]+[n+4/8]+[n+8/16] ...=n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Would someone please help me to prove the above relation? $[.]$ denotes the floor function $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: What are the brackets for?

Comment: @lightxbulb I would presume the floor function.

Comment: Probrably you meant $1/2, 1/4, 1/8,... $

Comment: $\frac{n+2^m}{2^{m + 1}}$ or $n+\frac{2^m}{2^{m+1}}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you edit the question like Michael wrote it in the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably $n$ is a positive integer and the equation should be written
$$\lfloor(n + 1)/2\rfloor + \lfloor(n + 2)/4\rfloor + \lfloor(n + 4)/8\rfloor + \cdots = n.$$
Sketch proof by induction: Suppose it's true for $n = m - 1$. For the step to $n = m$, let $2^k$ be the highest power of $2$ that divides $m$. The term $\lfloor(n + 2^k)/2^{k+1}\rfloor$ will increase by $1$ and all the others will stay the same.